# Load a modal with its controller as a service

Tags: angularjs, lazy-loading

I am trying to create a factory that loads the html template and then compile the html with the newly loaded controller...

```
app.factory('$modal', function ($templateProvider, $compile, $ocLazyLoad){
        return {
            open: function(modal) {
                $ocLazyLoad.load([
                  'modals/'+modal+'.html',
                  'modals/'+modal+'.ctrl.js',
                ]).then(function() {
                  // How ?
                })

            }
        }
    });
```

I also tried to get the html via `$templateProvider` after loading the controller with ocLazyLoad and then using the `$compile` service. The problem beeing at any time that the controller is not available !

In the config, I tried the following:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$httpProvider', '$locationProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$controllerProvider', '$compileProvider', '$filterProvider', '$provide', '$ocLazyLoadProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $controllerProvider, $compileProvider, $filterProvider, $provide, $ocLazyLoadProvider) {

        app.controller = $controllerProvider.register;
        app.directive = $compileProvider.directive;
        app.filter = $filterProvider.register;
        app.factory = $provide.factory;
        app.service = $provide.service;
        app.constant = $provide.constant;
        app.value = $provide.value;

    }]);
```

The idea being that I should be able to declare a new controller that just got loaded by using `angular.module('myApp').controller(...`. No success either.

I am stuck at this point, has anyone done that before ?

Comment: Can't you just inject the controller, and pass the path to the HTML template using the `templateUrl` property? (Example: `$uibModal.open( { templateUrl: 'modals/'+modal+'.html', controller: 'myCtrl' } );` - This gosed in the `then` part after you injected the controller using lazyload )

Comment: The AngularJS framework has two phases: config phase and run phase. No more configs are allowed after the run phase starts. This includes loading of other providers, controllers, directives, etc.